# Namespace Members in C++ (using vs not using)

Tags: c++, namespaces

So this is just a weird thought. I temporarily had what was essentially the following .h and .cpp files:

.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

namespace A {
    void FunctionOne();
}

using namespace A;

void FunctionTwo();

#endif
```

.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

void A::FunctionOne() {
    cout << "Function one!";
}

void A::FunctionTwo() {
    cout << "Function two!";
}
```

Now, this doesn't work. I get a compile-time error for "FunctionTwo" is not a member of "A". But that confused me a bit. I would have thought that it's just a matter of syntax.

If FunctionTwo is not a *member* of A when declared this way, then what is it?

Comment: you should post the complete example .

Comment: Sorry, what is B in this context.

Comment: This is not your real code. Presumably you meant `void A::FunctionTwo() {`

Comment: This is not an answer, just a plea: please don't do "using namespace" in the header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using namespace A;` doesn't mean the same as `namespace A { ... }`.

It allows for automatic lookup of symbols from namespace `A`, but it does not mean that every declaration following it is automatically declared into that namespace. In fact, it does pretty much nothing for declarations.

Thus, your `FunctionTwo` is still in the global namespace, and not part of the `A` namespace.

Comment: regarding the "using vs not-using" argument, it's probably a good idea to always use a different name for any function no matter how many namespaces you are using because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup which is a quite nasty trap in case of templates. It's also important to note that namespaces are compile time entities and the live and die during the compilation process, they are good at keeping things in order and I consider them a good side of C++, at a more practical level they also help you in the IDE with features such as the autocomplete, so, why not ?

Comment: @user2485710 So why not what?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a member of the global namespace, i.e. that namespace referred to by `::`, in this case: `::FunctionTwo()`.